# Configure linux to route traffic from internal network through ipsec tunnel (policy based)

Tags: iptables, routing, ipsec, strongswan

My company hosts cloud services. We have a partner that also hosts cloud services. We want to connect our network with theirs using ipsec / strongswan. Our clients should be able to reach the target servers using the `vpn-router-server` as a router / vopn gateway.

The setup looks like this:

[image: network setup as described in the text]

How do I need to configure my clients and the `vpn-router-server`?

Answer (score 3):

Notes:

- We don't really know nor care what the partner netowrk setup internally looks like in detail. We just know their vpn-endpoint public ip (`1.1.1.1`), their internal network (`10.10.10.0/24`) and the ip adress of their server(s) (for example `10.10.10.1`)
- Our `vpn-router-server` is a IAAS server hosted by a public cloud provider. It has a directly reachable external ip (`2.2.2.2`). It does use a gatway to reach the internet, however as the IAAS provider handles all of that, we dont include it in our diagram.

In this example we will focus on the following scenario:

- Our `client1` will send a `ping` to `target server1`. Other clients and target servers work the exact same way, just their ips are different.

---

On `client1`:

```
# tell the client to send all traffic for the partner network to the vpn-router-server
$ route add -net 10.10.10.0 gw 192.168.1.1
```

---

On `vpn-router-server`: `/etc/ipsec.conf`-configuration

```
config setup
  uniqueids = yes

conn con1
  aggressive = no
  fragmentation = yes
  keyexchange = ikev2
  mobike = yes
  reauth = yes
  rekey = yes
  forceencaps = no
  installpolicy = yes

  left = %any
  leftid = 2.2.2.2
  leftsubnet = 192.168.1.0/24
  leftauth = psk

  right = 1.1.1.1
  rightid = 1.1.1.1
  rightsubnet = 10.10.10.0/24
  rightauth = psk

  ikelifetime = 86400s
  lifetime = 3600s
  ike = aes256gcm16-sha512-ecp521!
  reqid = 1000
  esp = aes256-sha512-ecp521,aes256gcm16-sha512-ecp521,3des-sha512-ecp521,cast128-sha512-ecp521!
  auto = start
```

Set `iptable`-rules:

```
$ iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -o eth0 ! -p esp -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.1
```

- `-s 192.168.1.0/24` apply SNAT only to traffic from our internal network
- `-o eth0` apply SNAT only for traffic going out through the external interface eth0
- `! -p esp` Do not SNAT the DSP / ipsec traffic itself. This is the important part and I was missing this part before.
- `-j SNAT` SNAT the traffic
- `--to-source 192.168.1.1` Use the `vpn-router-server` internal ip as the source ip for the SNATed packets

---

The `client1` should now be able to ping `target server1`:

```
$ ping 10.10.10.1
```

You can analyse whats going on the `vpn-router-server` using `tcpdump`:

```
$ tcpdump -n -i eth0 icmp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
07:10:37.150680 IP 10.10.10.1 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo reply, id 7642, seq 1, length 64
07:10:38.152097 IP 10.10.10.1 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo reply, id 7642, seq 2, length 64
07:10:39.153237 IP 10.10.10.1 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo reply, id 7642, seq 3, length 64
07:10:40.153997 IP 10.10.10.1 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo reply, id 7642, seq 4, length 64
07:10:41.154766 IP 10.10.10.1 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo reply, id 7642, seq 5, length 64
07:10:42.155937 IP 10.10.10.1 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo reply, id 7642, seq 6, length 64

$ tcpdump -n -i eth1 icmp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
07:10:46.156162 IP 192.168.1.101 > 10.10.10.1: ICMP echo request, id 7642, seq 10, length 64
07:10:46.161079 IP 10.10.10.1 > 192.168.1.101: ICMP echo reply, id 7642, seq 10, length 64
07:10:47.157485 IP 192.168.1.101 > 10.10.10.1: ICMP echo request, id 7642, seq 11, length 64
07:10:47.162435 IP 10.10.10.1 > 192.168.1.101: ICMP echo reply, id 7642, seq 11, length 64
07:10:48.158920 IP 192.168.1.101 > 10.10.10.1: ICMP echo request, id 7642, seq 12, length 64
07:10:48.163772 IP 10.10.10.1 > 192.168.1.101: ICMP echo reply, id 7642, seq 12, length 64
07:10:49.160364 IP 192.168.1.101 > 10.10.10.1: ICMP echo request, id 7642, seq 13, length 64
07:10:49.165322 IP 10.10.10.1 > 192.168.1.101: ICMP echo reply, id 7642, seq 13, length 64
```